# Read data from ExpressJS server to display in pipe/ajax plugin of angular-smart-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, express, smart-table

**What I'm trying to do?**
I'm trying to learn Javascript & MEAN stack by developing a simple web application. In that application, I'm trying to use the "pipe/ajax plugin" of angular-smart-table in Web app with the below specs:
Client-side: AngularJS
Server-side: ExpressJS/NodeJS
(Created using Yeoman generator "generator-angular-fullstack")

**Challenge that I'm facing:**
I copy/pasted the pipe/ajax plugin example given in the smart table [documentation](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) in my web app. This example has the values to be displayed in the smart table in the client side (factory). I want to move these values to a server controller file (smartTableServer.controller.js in the plunker) accessible through the REST API endpoint $http.get('/api/smartTableServer').

**What I have achieved till now in this?**
I was able to successfully read the data from the server controller file into the client factory file (smartTableClient.service.js). However when I store it in a variable (randomsItems), the value of the variable is "undefined". I believe the http get call is executed later & hence the variable randomsItems still did not get the value from the server. Can you please help me to resolve this issue? (i.e.) Get the value of randomsItems from server controller JS & display it in the view.

**Plunker for my files relevant to this problem:**

```
`angular.module('myApp').factory('Resource', ['$q', '$filter', '$timeout', '$http', function ($q, $filter, $timeout, $http) {

    //this would be the service to call your server, a standard bridge between your model an $http
// the database (normally on your server)

function getrandomsItems() {  

     var defer = $q.defer();

     $http.get('/api/smartTableServer', { cache: 'true'}).success(

            function(randomsItems) {

                defer.resolve(randomsItems);

                //randomsItems = angular.fromJson(randomsItems);

                //console.log("Success - randomsItems : " + randomsItems);                    
                //console.log("Success - randomsItems.Stringify : " + JSON.stringify(randomsItems));

                return defer.promise;
            }                             
        );

    return defer.promise;
}

function getPage(start, number, params) {

var randomsItems = getrandomsItems(); // This method call returns the value as undefined!!!
...      `
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jRdNXuVMrWaymLnxfPnE?p=catalogue

*Please note:*
I still don't know how asynchronous scripting works & hence don't know defer & promise concepts which I think is the reason that I'm facing the above mentioned issue. I'm still learning the basics.Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function getRandomItems()` must take a callback that must be called inside `success` method of `$http.get('/api/smartTableServer', { cache: 'true'})` `promise`:

```
function getRandomItems(cb) {  
  $http.get('/api/smartTableServer', {cache: 'true'})
       .success(function(randomItems) { cb(randomItems); });
}

function getPage(start, number, params) {
  getRandomItems(function cb(randomItems) { 
    // do what you want to do with randomItems 
  };
)
```

Alternatively return a `promise` from `function getRandomItems()` and :

```
function getRandomItems(cb) {  
  return $http.get('/api/smartTableServer', {cache: 'true'});
}

function getPage(start, number, params) {
  getRandomItems.success(function(randomItems) { 
    // do what you want to do with randomItems 
  };
)
```

More docs here: [$http General usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and clear explanation. I was searching for such an example for 2 days. You made my day! Thanks.

Comment: Hi @kyrylkov! I was building on top of the above example & I'm facing the same issue again after I changed the http method from get to post. Did I miss something from your example? Here is the updated plunk with this issue (smartTableClient.service.js) -
http://plnkr.co/edit/WjSrJ7sHu8J11IqSLKrm Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @MohanasundaramVeeramuthu yes, you have the same problem again.  this time `getPage` doesn't take a callback.  obviously you're still confused about `callbacks` vs `promises`.  i suggest you start with re-writing `getRandomsItems` as i have suggested in my alternative example.  instead of passing a callback to it, rewrite it to return a promise.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was able to do it by returning a promise as you said. Thank you.